# Trouble Populating Grails Select Box with SQL Statement

Tags: sql, grails, select

I'm trying to populate a grails select with some rows returned from SQL but for some reason it is not working.  I have the following code:

Controller:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

class ClinicalRequirementsController {

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

def dataSource //injection of dataSource 

def create() {

     def db = new Sql(dataSource)

     def terms = db.rows("""SELECT stvterm_code
     FROM stvterm
     WHERE stvterm_fa_proc_yr = (SELECT stvterm_fa_proc_yr
     FROM stvterm, current_term
     WHERE stvterm_code = current_term.cur_term)
     ORDER BY stvterm_code ASC""")

     [terms: terms]

     db.close()

     [clinicalRequirementsInstance: new ClinicalRequirements(params)]
   }
}
```

GSP Select:

```
<g:select name="insuranceSemesterVerified" from="${terms}" required=""   value="${clinicalRequirementsInstance?.insuranceSemesterVerified}" valueMessagePrefix="clinicalRequirements.insuranceSemesterVerified"/>
```

I'm pretty stumped.  Hopefully someone can point me towards what is wrong.  I've already verified the query against the database elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The controller returns the last line only (unless you put a `return` statement in there somewhere), so change your last line to this:

```
[clinicalRequirementsInstance: new ClinicalRequirements(params), terms: terms]
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick.  What would be the best way of being able to reuse that code among my other gsps without having to put the code in each separate controller?

Comment: For doing this I usually create a custom taglib and have that taglib render the g:select - your call would be similar to:

Comment: Sorry - last comment got cut off: For doing stuff like this I usually create a custom taglib and have that taglib render the `g:select`. Or you could create a service method that returned the list; then you would wire your service into any gsp that needed the list (see question 2510929 for an example of this).  Your select would then have a `from` like; `from="${myService.listTerms()}"`

Comment: I should have asked this first - is `stvterm` a Grails domain class (or can it be mapped as one)?  If so the solution is much easier - you can then directly use domain methods in your gsp like `from="${StvTerm.list()}"`. You can also create custom methods in the domain to handle different needs, like `listOnlyCurrentTerm` and use those in your gsp as well.